# Composite ViewModels in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I came accross the following situation:

I have 2 view models and a single view which contains 2 user controls on which the view models will be bound to. The first VM is a Search functionality which returns a list of Persons, and the second VM is a more detailed description of each person.

I want to do the following:

```
public CompositeVM
{
     public SearchVM SearchViewModel{get;set;}
     public DescriptionVM DescriptionViewModel{get;set;}
}
```

As I have said, the search view model also incorporates a list of found persons, so I wish that when I select a person the DescriptionVM to be updated accordingly.

How can I achieve this type of communication between VMs? Should I set a SelectedPerson property on the SearchVM and pass it to the DescriptionVM when the selected list item changes (pretty high coupling to me)? Is there a more simple approach to this matter?

Comment: Why you don't add the DescriptionViewModel as a property of SearchVM? Then you still can bind UserControl to it ... {Binding SearchViewModel.DescriptionViewModel}

Comment: Well I thought of that, but the DescriptionVM is more complex that just viewing some properties: it also has some functionality for editing, creating, etc and I didn't ant this functionality to be interwined with the searching. Also, the searching has more complex functionality as well. I just thought that it would be better (architecturally) that these VMs should be separated and aggregated in a composite VM.

Comment: Ok, that's a good reason. So do you design same ViewModel for different views?(just curious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible for `CompositeVM` to subscribe to `SearchViewModel`'s `PropertyChanged` event and set `DescriptionViewModel.SetSelectedPerson(SearchViewModel.SelectedPerson)`.

There is no coupling here between `SearchVM` and `DescriptionVM`, since they're not aware of each other. `CompositeVM` knows them both, and is also who's in charge of their interaction.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your answer for the maintaining low coupling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the Mediator-Observer pattern, such as the Messenger class in MVVM Light:

http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Comment: The Messenger class is pretty useful, but for my school project it seems like an overhead..

Comment: Why not implement your own simpler version? If MVVM itself is not an overkill for your project...